# You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page. (Youtube data API)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get my youtube API key. I created a new project and enabled YouTube Data API.
After that when I go to "Credentials" tab, I got this error: **ERROR You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page**.
(please see the screen shot).

[image]

Please help me.

Regards,
Den

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page, or logging out and back in already?

Comment: this is the issue with google developer console. excess of security making life a hell for using any of google apis